# Destroying a handshake after logout. socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Hello I am trying to build chat into an application. What I am wondering is when the user logs out of the website how do I also destroy the socket.io handshake associated with that session so the user cannot send messages from say another tab when he is logged out.

I am using expressjs if that is any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well in case anyone ever find this and wants to know I did figure it out.
You can access the sockets disconnect function. I had object of users ids and their socket id so when someone logged out I called

```
app.get("/logout", function(req,res){
  //do other logging out stuff
  sockets.disconnectUser(req.session.user_id);
}

// Disconnect User function
sockets.disconnectUser = function(user_id){
  sockets.socket(users[user_id]).disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The socket.io object contains information about all connected sockets and the sessionID of each socket. Thus, it is possible to iterate through the connected sockets and disconnect those which are associated with the sessionID that is logging out. There is no need to manually track user and socket ids in this approach.

Example code tested with socket.io@2.2.0, express@4.17.1 and express-session@1.16.2.

```js
const SocketIO = require('socket.io');

let sio = new SocketIO;

app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  //do other logging out stuff
  logoutSocketsIO(req.sessionID);
});


// Iterate through all connected sockets and close those which are associated
// with the given sessionID
// Note: One sessionID can have multiple sockets (e.g. many browser tabs)
function logoutSocketsIO(sessionID) {    
  let connections = sio.sockets.connected;
  for(let c in connections) {
    let socketSessionID = connections[c].conn.request.sessionID;
    if(sessionID === socketSessionID) {
      connections[c].disconnect();
    }
  }
}
```