# Socket.io authorization is still persistent although user is logged out on the website

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io, passport.js

I'm using the [express-socket.io-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session) on my app. I've integrated it and it works properly. There is only one case though.

Have a look at the following code:

```
io.use(...);
io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {

    socket.onVerify = (msg, fn) => {
        socket.on(msg, (data) => {

            console.log(socket.handshake.session.passport);

            if (typeof socket.handshake.session.passport === "undefined") {
                socket.emit("auth failed emit", {
                    msg: "Please login via the website"
                });
                return false;
            }

            fn(data, socket.handshake.session);
        });
    }

    socket.onVerify("chat message", function (req, session) {
        Chat.publish(session.email, req.msg);
    });
});
```

Basically, on each socket request, I verify `socket.handshake.session.passport` being defined, which means user is logged in.

It works in this case:

- I open a browser tab, login with my credentials, get redirected to /game endpoint where my game loads and connects to socket.io
- I click on "logout" button, get redirected to /game endpoint, game tells me "I need to authorize."

However, it doesn't work in this case:

- I open a browser tab, login with my credentials, get redirected to /game endpoint where my game loads and connects to socket.io
- I click on "logout" button ON A NEW TAB, and logout in that tab.
- I switch back to main tab, and game is still online.

I added a debug in my code (`console.log(socket.handshake.session.passport)`) and it shows `{ user: 1 }` although I logged out already so it must be `undefined`

For some reason, socket.io handshake/session doesn't recognize it, so I probably need to refresh it on certain cases.

Is there any way to do it with socket.io?

Comment: What does `socket.handshake.session.user` contain when (not) logged in?

Comment: `undefined` both when I'm logged in and logged out.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, Passport sets `req.user` to `req.session.passport.user`, I mistakenly thought that it would also set it as `req.session.user`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a try to resolve your issue, i'm not really sure it would work. But you could try something like that :

```
app.get("/logout", function(req,res){
  //do other logging out stuff
  sockets.disconnectUser(req.session.user_id);
}

// Disconnect User function
sockets.disconnectUser = function(user_id){
  sockets.socket(users[user_id]).disconnect();
}
```

Like described here : [Destroying a handshake after logout. socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293188/destroying-a-handshake-after-logout-socket-io)